# Monogame - Loading multiple tiles

Tags: c#, for-loop, xna, monogame

I'm having some issues loading multiple tiles to my game. My game world currently has a pixel size of 770x450. I have loaded a single tile at position (0, 330), and wanted to make a loop that copies and loads the tile along the x axis until it reaches (770, 330).

I have been able to make this loop, however upon every loop, **the next tile doesn't load**, it just moves to the next position, here's the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 770; i += 31)
{
    position = new Vector2(i, 330);
    // Some sort of draw method here!
    if (i == 744)
    {
        i = i + 26;
        // or here...
        position = new Vector2(i, 330);
        // or maybe here?
    }
}
```

And if this helps, here's my current `Draw()` method:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(gameTile, position, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only drawing the tile once. You can tell because you only have one `spriteBatch.Draw()` call. It doesn't do enough to just update the position inside the loop. You have to draw it at each location as well.

```
public void Draw()
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < 770; i += 31)
    {
        position = new Vector2(i, 330);
        if (i == 744)
        {
            i = i + 26;
            position = new Vector2(i, 330);
        }
        spriteBatch.Draw(gameTile, position, Color.White);
    }

    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Of course, you want to avoid all that loopy logic in the `Draw()` method. The only way around that is to create a tile for every position you want it drawn at in your `Update()` method. Then the `Draw()` method could just loop through all of your gameTiles and draw them at their corresponding position.